# Griffin.Container / Griffin.Decoupled: Registration of the container itself

Tags: c#-4.0, domain-driven-design

I currently take a look at the `Griffin.Decoupled` and `Griffin.Container` libraries.
In my ASP.MVC4 application I want to use the `IocQueryDispatcher` in the first steps.

My problem is the registration with 
`registrar.RegisterType<IQueryDispatcher, IocQueryDispatcher>`
because the `IocQueryDispatcher` has a `IServiceLocator` dependency.

The current registration in the ASP.MVC application looks like

```
protected static void Register(ContainerRegistrar registrar)
{
    registrar.RegisterType<IQueryDispatcher, IocQueryDispatcher>();
    // this dont works because the _container is null
    registrar.RegisterInstance<IServiceLocator>(_container);
}

public static void Configure()
{
    var registrar = new ContainerRegistrar();
    registrar.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    registrar.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    Register(registrar);
    // this method creates a new container
    _container = registrar.Build();

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new GriffinWebApiDependencyResolver(_container);
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new GriffinDependencyResolver(_container));
}
```

How should the IServiceLocator / the container itself can be registered?
(The container should registered as singleton)

After analyzing the the libraries I can't find a way of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to install the adapter between Griffin.Decoupled and Griffin.Container:

```
install-package griffin.decoupled.container
```

Then simply replace the registration lines with:

```
registrar.DispatchQueries();
```

Samples can be found here: https://github.com/jgauffin/Samples/tree/master/Griffin.Decoupled

Comment: ah, missed to look @ the samples.